# What is this stylish R-like symbol?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, control-theory

[image: screenshot from Sliding Mode Control: Theory And Applications (Book by Christopher Edwards and Sarah Spurgeon) Page 37]

What is that stylish R-like symbol at the end of the statement? I combed the lists of linear algebra symbols from almost every source online. Some guesses were Row space (which might make sense, just that I can't find any sources) and Rank (which doesn't make any sense...)

The book is Sliding Mode Control: Theory And Applications (by Christopher Edwards and Sarah Spurgeon) page 37.

Comment: Notation means whatever the author intends it to mean.  Not every author uses the same notation.  Notation used in a textbook should hopefully be defined during the relevant chapters when it was introduced or included in an index or appendix at the front or back.

Comment: That said, it makes sense for $\mathcal{R}$ to denote *range* (*not rowspace*) and $\mathcal{N}$ to denote nullspace given the context.

Comment: For the record, it's (perhaps up to some hardly perceivable differences) a capital R in "Calligraphic" font (latex command mathcal) $\mathcal R$.

Comment: @JMoravitz You're right. I assumed the book did not have such a list. I did find one though, in the appendix. And it is the range of A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathcal R(A)$ is not an uncommon notation for the row space of $A$. Neither is just $R(A)$. I'm not sure which sources you're consulting, but I've seen both.

However, the ultimate authority on notation is the textbook itself. If you go to p. 207 of the textbook (A.1 Mathematical Notation in the table of contents), you see the line

> $\mathcal R(A) \quad$ the range space of the matrix $A$ (viewed as a linear operator)

and so that's what it is. You might be more used to saying "column space" instead of "range space".